# Sharing objects across routes

Tags: node.js, express, keen-io

Trying out Keen.io and wondering if it's possible to NOT have to call "configure" in each file that will make a call to the Keen API?

Their docs from here: https://github.com/keenlabs/KeenClient-node show how to configure an instance which I use in one of my routes but I have a number of routes and find that I have to keep configuring.

```
var Keen = require('keen.io');

// Configure instance. Only projectId and writeKey are required to send data.
var client = Keen.configure({
  projectId: "<project_id>",
  writeKey: "<write_key>",
  readKey: "<read_key>",
  masterKey: "<master_key>"
});
```

Is there a way to "configure" just once or have I got the wrong idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to configure the app in`server.js` and then pass the `client` object to each route that requires it. This appears to work well and has tidied my code up considerably.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21133217/283866) to another question on SO. It describes a method to use `app.get()` and `app.set()` to access dependencies across the application.

After you configure `client`, set it in the app:

```
app.set('keen', client);
```

Then later get it back out from within any route:

```
var client = app.get('keen');
```