# scribe js error - console.log not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, scribe-js

I was using scribe js like

**app.js**

```
var scribe = require('scribe-js')();
var console=process.console;
app.use(scribe.express.logger());
app.use('/logs', scribe.webPanel());
```

and in my

**module.js**

```
var like = 0;
var error=require('./error');
var console=process.console;  <-- this line
//only works if i comment above line
//else it shows console not defined

var like_dislike = {
    like: function(req, res, next) {
        like++;
        console.log(process.console);
        console.log("Like:" + like + " ClientTime:" + req.query.timestamp);
        res.sendStatus(200)
    }
}
module.exports=like_dislike
```

Any Idea, atleast where to start looking to resolve this ?

Thanks

EDIT
error.js

```
function error(res, custom_error, actual_error) {
    if (actual_error)
        console.error(actual_error);
    res.status(custom_error.status).send(custom_error.text);
}
module.exports=error;
```

Comment: isn't `console` off the global object?

Comment: what u mean by "off the global object" ? And ya if i do `console.log(process)` i can see a console object

Comment: The `global` object has a property called `console`. In the browser, the global object has a property called `window` that refers to itself and in `node`, the global object can be accessed through `GLOBAL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the express router does not maintain a reference to the console variable (or process, it seems) while passing the request along to the handler.  This problem persists even you you try to use the console variable inside an anonymous handler in the same file (not loading a submodule).

The solution is to cache a reference to Scribes console in `app.locals` and access it via `req.app.locals.console`.  More details at this question: [Global Variable in app.js accessible in routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765215/global-variable-in-app-js-accessible-in-routes)

I sent you a pull request on github.  the updates that I have made are marked with comments in the style of:

```
/*
 * update explination
 */
```

Comment: hey i know that , but scribe attaches its own console

Comment: so ideally without putting `this line` in module.js , i should be able to use console.tag('abc').log('xyz') but i am not , it just logs in scribe without tag

Comment: I see, Scribe is modifying console.  After re-reading your question, it seems that your problem is not with console, but with `./error`.  What is inside of the `./error` script?

Comment: even if i remove error.js , same issue , and frustrating part is i don't know where to begin

Comment: Then I am misunderstanding what you mean when you say:  '<-- this line only works if i comment above line else it shows console not defined'.

Does console.log() work if you comment the `...require('./error')` line, or does it work when you comment out the `var console...` line

Comment: Are you working from a branch that hasn't been pushed yet?  I don't see anything relevant to scribe and I don't see module.js or error.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103348/discussion-between-brady-cartmell-and-aishwat-singh).

Comment: I've updated the answer.  I've also sent you a pull request on GitHub with the necessary changes.

Comment: i ended up using process.console() in every line instead of var console=process.console that way it works. But Thanks man , really u went the extra mile to help me out. Thanks a lot :)