# Express : Does mysql queries in app.js make sense

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Does app.js get processed only once?. In that case, does it make sense to run setup queries in app.js so that I don't have to run it on every request?.

I have a table to countries and regions that I need in several requests.

I am looking at an implementation something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21133217/406659

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No putting this in `app.js` does not make sense. I would create a `models` folder and encapsulate all of your database logic in a module within that folder. Then on startup of the app (ie on `app.listen()` callback) I would call a method from that module which  does the setup for me. For example:

Some DB module in `models`

```
module.exports = {
   setup: () => {
    // Set up logic here - checking if tables exist etc
   }
}
```

Then in `app.js` or equal

```
require <SOME DB MODULE>

app.listen(<PORT>, () => {
   <SOME DB MODULE>.setup();
})
```

**Note this is a generalised approach as I don't know the specifics of your setup - This approach just ensures encapsulated and reusable code. I've also used ES6 syntax where possible.**

Hope this helps

Dylan

Comment: my query was more to do with is it ok to do in app.js. All my model code is in models folder.

Comment: Fair enough - generally speaking you could do your whole app in `app.js` but it's not a good idea. In answer to the original question calling a setup function in `app.js` is no problem and probably the best place to do it as long as its abstracted. As long as those tables are there before you need them then its fine :)

Comment: will these queries be called on each request or only once

Comment: If you do it on `app.listen()` it will only be called once on app startup. Make sure you put in logic to check if tables exist and there is data in them so you don't double up