# Node.js global variable only works once

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

I have a global variable in my server side code inside a post route and i am trying to access it within another post route. The code executes perfectly when the second post route is called for the first time, but when the second post route is triggered a second time, the value of the global variable becomes `undefined`.

Snippet of first post route that declares the global variable:

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
    ...
    fs.readFile('results.json', function (err, data) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err)

    } else{    

    var json = JSON.parse(data)

    ...

    global.Identifier;
    global.Identifier = Identifier;
    return global.Identifier;

    } 
    }

);
res.redirect("/");
});
```

snippet of second post request that accesses global variable:

```
app.post("/addtask", function(req, res) {
    var gloablIdentifier = global.Identifier;
    ...
    res.redirect("/");
};
```

(When the second post request is accessed a second time, the value of `gloablIdentifier` = `undefined` )

**NOTE:** I understand that using global variables is VERY BAD PRACTICE and should be avoided in most situations at all costs, but I would still like to work on this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like you want a session variable, rather than a global one. Not sure why the global doesn't work but it might be Node cleaning up between routes or a different side-effect that results in this.

Comment: How does your node program run?

Comment: @evolutionxbox When a user logs in, their details are identified by the Identifier variable in the first post route and the second post route is responsible for displaying the details on the screen. (I understand that this is very insecure and would lead to many privacy issues and using something like passport.js would be a lot better)

Comment: Do you run your code in a “lambda” or other short life instance?

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, I haven't done this

Comment: REST API's should be stateless. keeping/using the data calculated on another request is violating the same. you can return the response from first request and client needs to cache that data (if cacheable) and send the same in successive requests as per requirement.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm quite new to node.js and am unsure of how to change global variables into session variables. Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

You did not wait readFile has to be finished and return `response`. Since, `fs.readFile` is async, `global.Identifier` will update later. You can await to read the file and then return;

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile("results.json", function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      var json = JSON.parse(data);
      global.Identifier = Identifier;
      return global.Identifier;
    }
    // wait for read file
    res.redirect("/");
  });
  // res.redirect("/");
});
```

**async-await version:**

```
const { promisify } = require("util");
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

app.post("/login", async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const data = await readFile("results.json");
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    global.Identifier = Identifier;
    return res.redirect("/");
  } catch (error) {
    return res.redirect("/");
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the second post route works perfectly when its accessed the first time.

Comment: Unfortunately the same error persists after implementing this solution.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you are using something like Express.

Even though this might be a bad practice I think that you should give a try to using the `set` functionality provided by express itself.

As such, in your app.js do it like this:

```
app.set("identifier", Identifier)
```

Then, in your routes:

```
app.post("/addtask", function(req, res) {
    var gloablIdentifier = app.get('identifier')
    ...
    res.redirect("/");
};
```

I did not test this, it's based on the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get) and on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21133217/13058340) answer

EDIT: I tested this and it works. Also, to change the variable again just do this on your route:

`app.set('identifier', newValue)`

I hope the answer is complete now!

Comment: Identifier is a variable, will this method allow the value of Identifier to change?

Comment: I updated my answer, please check if it's complete now!

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately the same error persists after implementing this solution.