# Global Variable in Node Express and Access Inside a Class File

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my Node Express app I have created a variable in app.js as shown below:

```
let accounts = [checkingAccount, savingAccount]
```

Now, I have a separate file called account.js (Not a route) just a class file. And I want to access the accounts array. How can I do that?

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765215/global-variable-in-app-js-accessible-in-routes

Comment: @AayushMall My question is quite different. My account.js is a model file not a route.

Comment: You can assign it globals variable of the Node Js and use it further

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/globals-in-node-js/

Answer (score 2):

in your `app.js` use export

```
module.exports.accounts = ["checkingAccount", "savingAccount"];
```

and then in your `account.js`

```
accounts = require("./app.js");
```

Comment: In my account.js I am requiring account.js ?? I dont understand.

Comment: Also keep in mind that account.js is not a route. It is a model file.

Comment: Sorry, I Have changed that, yes you should be able to import/require the variables in your `account.js`  module

Comment: That works but now inside app.js file it says accounts is not defined.

Comment: are checkingAccount , savingAccount functions ?

Comment: They are just objects. Also inside account.js accounts is an object instead of an array.

Comment: Why does module.exports.accounts end up being an object which contains accounts array.

Comment: because the [module.exports](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut) is an object that allows you to expose your module. if you want to access the array just do smth like `const getarray=require("./app.js") ` and then `getarray.accounts `