# In Node.js / Express how do I gain access to an object in app.js from a module 2 layers deep?

Tags: node.js, redis

**Background:** In order to log out a user I need to gain access to an object `redisClient` located in `app.js`.  How do I access `redisClient` from a module 2 levels deep?  I'm not sure how to work my way back to the fresh version of `redisClient` from downstream of it.

**From app.js**

```
const session = require('express-session');
const redis = require('redis');
const redisClient = redis.createClient();
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

const myEndpoints = require('./controllers/my-endpoints');
app.use(myEndpoints);
```

**From my-endpoints.js**

```
const router = express.Router();
const someMiddleware = require('./some-middleware');
router.get('/logout', someMiddleware.logout);

module.exports = router;
```

**From some-middleware.js**

```
exports.logout = function(req, res) {

    // uh oh I'm 2 layers deep.  How do I get to redisClient from here?
    redisClient.del(req.session.id, function(err, response) {
        console.log(err);
    });


    req.session.destroy(function(error) {

        if (error) res.clearCookie(process.env.SESSION_NAME);
        res.redirect('/');

    });
}
```

Comment: I think you can store it with `app.set('myClient', redisClient)` and then later get it with `app.get('myClient')`

Comment: [`req.app`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.app) contains the `app` object so the middleware can get the app object from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765215/global-variable-in-app-js-accessible-in-routes/21133217#21133217) it was an easy fix.  Thanks to the comments for pointing me in this direction.

**In app.js:**

```
app.set('referenceToRedisClient', redisClient);
```

**In some-middleware.js:**

```
let redisClient = req.app.get('referenceToRedisClient');
await redisClient.del(req.session.id);
```