# Is it secure to export variables from the main.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

I've been looking for a way to share/reference variables from my `main.js` to a router file. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765215/global-variable-in-app-js-accessible-in-routes) question and tried sharing the variable over the locals of the app, which did work, but it required to get the variable from the locals for each route. So I thought I might just export the variables I need and import them in the router file, which also works, but makes me worried that the variables are exposed.
It looks like this:

main.js

```js
//imports
const APP = express();
const httpServer = createServer(APP);
export const io = new Server(httpServer);

// APP configuration

export const sessionStore = new MySQLStoreInstance(storeOptions);
...
```

router.js

```js
import {io, sessionStore} from "../main.js";
...
```

Is it secure to share variables this way, or are they exposed in some way? If it's not secure, how can I securely share variables between files?

Comment: Secure in what context? Exposed to whom? This looks like backend code, and if an untrusted party has access to that environment you've got bigger problems than an export.

Comment: "secure" is not a binary concept, it's a continuum. You need to weigh security against functionality, and determine which threats you're trying to protect against.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was wondering if the variables are accessible from outside, but yeah, what you say makes sense